# Android Google Maps API V2: Exchange location information between 2 users who have same app

Tags: android, geolocation

I am currently working on an android application for my class. Our app is to help friends find each other. However for us to do so we need to exchange location data between those 2 users.

I want to know if there is a way for android to send/receive location data to another user with the same app, without having to use an intermediary server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not, you have to have a server implementation in order for the user to store their location and be able to pull down their friends locations.

However, you might be able to set this up pretty simply with a service like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/). They make it easy to store data for your app without having to build your own back end.

Comment: ahh dang. Thanks for the info. I briefly looked at Parse and looks very promising.

Comment: Parse is great! I would also recommend Firebase as well https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: Thanks for letting me introducing me to Firebase as well! As far as live time syncing it seems to me firebase has the API's to do so. I didn't see any (or come across) listener methods in Parse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar application. And you need a intermediary server. You must send the coordinates from the mobile to server. And then you must access from the other cell to server (using a webservice), and download coordinates.